Angular@ Interact - change - apply element value only with console
I am not trying to develop an angular app. There is this website and I am trying to create a script to make myself click less when having to fill out form. However, the website is in Angular and I am having a hard time learning this, as I've done this before but only with normal HTML element. I am not a developer or anything.
The page is not recognised as an angular app as the heading is this
<html ng-app2="core" 

Anyway, there is this drop down field with the below when inspected:
<select ng-if="vm.mode != 'view' && !vm.isEmptyObject(property.options)" ng-model="property.value" ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in property.options" ng-change="vm.statusChanged(property.value)" ng-required="property.mandatory" ng-selected="1" name="h_record_state" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" selected="selected" required="required" style="">

<option value="" class=""></option>
<option label="Current" value="string:0">Current</option>
<option label="Active" value="string:1" selected="selected">Active</option>
<option label="Archived" value="string:2">Archived</option>

</select>

I can get the scope of this field. But from there, I can't see anything I can change
$$ChildScope: null
$$childHead: null
$$childTail: null
$$listenerCount: {$destroy: 2}
$$listeners: {$destroy: Array(2)}
$$nextSibling: null
$$prevSibling: m {$id: 724, $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null,  $nextSibling: b, …}
$$transcluded: true
$$watchers: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
$$watchersCount: 6
$id: 1083
$parent: m {$$childTail: b, $$childHead: m, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array(5), $$listeners: {…}, …}
[[Prototype]]: m

So, I can change the selected drop down with normal document.querySelector(Element).SelectedIndex, but I cannot apply change to the form on the page when I click the Save (Submit) button.
I am struggling with the syntax to access the angular element and directives from within the console. There are other field/drop down and autocomplete fields on the page too but I want to get the basic to work first in the learning curve.
Read many guides or posts about scope(), apply() etc but I can't get it to work with this page I want.
I really need a pointer on how to just use console to change and apply the value, as I don't have access to the backend of this page, and most guides I've read were about how to do angular stuff when developing an app

So I've managed to change the value of the text field and drop down fields using NOT angular syntax, but javascript with something like
document.getElementsByName('h_record_state')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'), {bubbles:true})
However, I have now an Autocomplete field which I am stuck with. Would anyone be willing to take a look so I can post the relevant HMTL code with that element?
